# Text mining Error- Getting this error while creating the DocumentTermMatrix & Word Cloud

Tags: word-cloud, term-document-matrix

I am getting an error message '**Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i, j, v, nrow = length(terms), ncol = length(corpus),  : 
  'i, j' invalid'**

While creating the DocumentTermMatrix or creating a Word Cloud.This is happening in all data sets.Here is the code I used

```
corpus=tm_map(corpus,tolower)
corpus=tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation)
corpus=tm_map(corpus,removeWords,stopwords("english"))
corpus=tm_map(corpus,stemDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
library("SnowballC")
dtm=DocumentTermMatrix(corpus) 

library("wordcloud")
wordcloud(corpus,min.freq=4,scale=c(5,1),random.color=F,max.words=45,random.order=F)
```

I have recently changed my computer and Reinstalled R(3.3.4).Not sure if that is causing this problem.Everything was working fine on the old PC.Please help.

PS: I tried to read through all the available questions this topic and suggestions like installing 'SnowballC' package etc are not helping me
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Nidhin VC

Answer (score 0):

remove
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)